# Install on VirtualBox seems stuck on "Running post install"

Tags: 14.04, virtualbox, mac

The install on VirtualBox 4.3.14 seems stuck on "Running post-install triggers software-center".

It has been at this screen for over an hour. Can I skip this step?

```
7/19/14 9:07:20.973 AM VirtualBox[37183]: modalSession has been exited prematurely - check for a reentrant call to endModalSession: 
7/19/14 12:22:50.911 PM VirtualBox[37183]: -_continuousScroll is deprecated for NSScrollWheel. Please use -hasPreciseScrollingDeltas. 
7/19/14 12:22:50.911 PM VirtualBox[37183]: -deviceDeltaX is deprecated for NSScrollWheel. Please use -scrollingDeltaX. 
7/19/14 12:22:50.911 PM VirtualBox[37183]: -deviceDeltaY is deprecated for NSScrollWheel. Please use -scrollingDeltaY.
```

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 on a Mac.

Comment: Please add version of Ubuntu and Virtualbox you are using.

Comment: Unbuntu:ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso

Comment: Ubuntu:ubuntu-14.04-desktop-amd64+mac.iso ; VirtualBox: 4.3.14. Sorry for the incomplete previous response.

Comment: Additiona information from console log on my mac:

Comment: 7/19/14 9:07:20.973 AM VirtualBox[37183]: modalSession has been exited prematurely - check for a reentrant call to endModalSession:
7/19/14 12:22:50.911 PM VirtualBox[37183]: -_continuousScroll is deprecated for NSScrollWheel. Please use -hasPreciseScrollingDeltas.
7/19/14 12:22:50.911 PM VirtualBox[37183]: -deviceDeltaX is deprecated for NSScrollWheel. Please use -scrollingDeltaX.
7/19/14 12:22:50.911 PM VirtualBox[37183]: -deviceDeltaY is deprecated for NSScrollWheel. Please use -scrollingDeltaY.

Comment: @user2459613 Are you still experiencing (and seeking help with) this problem?

Answer (score 0):

I experienced a similar problem on VirtualBox 5.0.

I solved it by unchecking "Install this third-party software" checkbox during the preparation process of Ubuntu installation.